# Куда уходят папки и файлы при смене ветки Git или переход на другой комит, в локальном репозитории?

Tags: git

Интересно, куда уходят папки и файлы при смене ветки Git или переход на другой комит, в локальном репозитории?

Comment: git их удаляет, видимо

Comment: Они уходят в цифровую нирвану.

Comment: в локальном репозитории (т.е. в содержимом каталога `.git`) не меняется вообще ничего (ну, разве что кроме ссылок `.git/HEAD .git/refs/*` и т.п.)

Answer (score 4):

В репозитории есть два типа файлов, назовем их файлы проекта и файлы системы управления версиями (т.е. в нашем случае git). Файлы проекта - те файлы, с которыми напрямую работает разработчик, и файлы git - файлы, которая лежат в папке .git, и разработчик с ними дела не имеет.

Начнем со вторых, т.к. там проще.

В папке .git содержится информация о всех коммитах репозитория. При переходе по коммитам или смене веток (что в принципе тоже переход на другой коммит) с файлами в папке .git совершенно ничего не происходит (кроме разве что содержимого файла HEAD и пары других, но это нас не интересует).

С файлами проекта происходит следующее: файлы, отсутствующие в том коммите/ветке, куда мы переключаемся, просто удаляются (не в корзину!). Файлы, имеющее другое содержание, перезаписываются. Идентичные файлы не трогаются.

Comment: Так вот 
вы говорите что "просто удаляются(не в корзину)", но вот когда переходим обратно то они вновь появляются. в этом и заключается мой вопрос. Где именно хранится память о коммитах?

Comment: Третий абзац - в папке ,git

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, конечно, интересный

Я думаю, git перезаписывает файлы, а если необходимо - удаляет/создаёт их

Comment: но если файл такой же, то перезаписывать его не обязательно. Иначе на больших репозиториях переключение веток было бы долгое.

Comment: ну перезаписывает не все файлы конечно