# Как Jupyter Notebook узнает, что Git Bash переключил ветку?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, git-bash

Как Jupyter Notebook (или другая программа для редактирования файлов) узнает, что Git Bash переключил ветку и необходимо открыть файл из новой ветки?

Comment: Никак. Редакторы вообще не знают ни о каких ветках, а просто открывают те файлы, которые имеются. Почитай что-нибудь о том, как работает гит.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел здесь [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164867/Куда-уходят-папки-и-файлы-при-смене-ветки-git-или-переход-на-другой-комит-в-лок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164867/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-git-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA).

При переключении веток Git заменяет все содержимое проекта (файлы и папки).
Jupyter Notebook просто открывает файл с указанным адресом.