# Как настроить чтобы файлы проекта в директории локального репозитория не исчезали при смене ветки git в программе VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

При работе с репозиторием через программу SmartGit если создается и выбирается новая ветка, то файлы из других веток никуда не пропадают и видны в директории локального репозитория.
А если создавать или выбирать ветку в программе VS Code, то файлы и каталоги других веток пропадают из директории локального репозитория. Как это исправить?
Вот был похожий вопрос, но там не было решения как это изменить:
[Куда уходят папки и файлы при смене ветки Git или переход на другой комит, в локальном репозитории?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164867/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-git-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0):

Я использую git stash для того, чтобы "спрятать" изменения в какой-либо ветке перед переходом/созданием другой. После переключения обратно просто извлекаю stash. Можно для этого использовать и меню в VS Code.

[image: Картиночка]

Comment: У меня VS Code при нажатии Pop Stash (извлечь спрятанное) выдает There are no stashes in the repository.

Comment: @Святослав Скорее всего ты сначала ничего не добавил в stash. ДОбавляешь в stash - перключаешься на дргую ветку - делаешь что тебе надо в этой ветке - возврращаешься назад - делаешь pop stash. 

Попробуй еще расширение для VS Code "Git Lens". Там можно будет посмотреть тайники, которые ты создавал.

Меню с изменениями слева и там внизу будет меню "STASHES".